# HTML & Javascript Page appears blank

Tags: javascript, html

Platform i use to code : "Sublime Text."
So, Whenever i try to open my html files on chrome or any browser my page turns blank. My latest project i followed the exact same codes as the youtuber did and still my page turns blank. Whats the problem, the html is saved as .html and javascript as .js

Here is my site code : 
Index (Saved as index.html)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Happy Guinea Pigs</title>
    <script src="Box2dWeb-2.1.a.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="boxbox.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="game" width=640 height=380>
      Text that you see if you don't support Canvas :(
    </canvas>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then game.js

```
var canvasElem = document.getElementById("game");
var world = boxbox.createWorld(canvasElem);

world.createEntity({
  name: "player",
  shape: "circle",
  radius: 1,
  image: "pig.png",
  imageStretchToFit: true,
  density: 4,
  x: 2,
  onKeyDown: function(e) {
    this.applyImpulse(200, 60);
  }
});

world.createEntity({
  name: "ground",
  shape: "square",
  type: "static",
  color: "rgb(0,100,0)",
  width: 20,
  height: .5,
  y: 12
});

var block = {
  name: "block",
  shape: "square",
  color: "brown",
  width: .5,
  height: 4,
  onImpact: function(entity, force) {
    if (entity.name() === "player") {
      this.color("black");
    }
  }
};

world.createEntity(block, {
  x: 15
});

world.createEntity(block, {
  x: 17
});

world.createEntity(block, {
  x: 16,
  y: 1,
  width: 4,
  height: .5
});
```

So i save these two as index.html and game.js Once i open the index.html in my browser, nothing at all appears, not the images, circles or anything. Just a pure blank page.. What am i doing wrong here? Just plain html code works fine always.

Excuse me for my bad english and i really hope to get a answer as im very exited on learning more about web development. I have tried a loong time to figure out the problem but havent had any luck. Thats why im asking here. Thanks for any help x)

Comment: If you check the browser console it might provide some information that will be help to debug.

Comment: Sure all three JS files are in the same folder as index.html?

Comment: Are you running this on an actual server, or just on your computer (double clicking the index.html file in your file-browser)?

Comment: Try running a simple python server `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`  on ur machine in the code folder and then access the page at `0.0.0.0:8080/`.  As you have **canvas** element in your js file the browser will not allow you to run the `js` file. You can also take a look at this [answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/79751).

Comment: @Will yes i am sure they are

Comment: @myfunkyside Just clicking the index.html file :)

Comment: You could use [**XAMPP**](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) to run on local machine (it simulates running on a remote server), but in my opinion the real thing is always best. *([Some tutorials on installing XAMPP](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=how+to+install+xampp))*

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the ***code snippet***, ***jsfiddle*** and ***codepen*** below, in principal your code works:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvasElem = document.getElementById("game");
  var world = boxbox.createWorld(canvasElem);
  
  world.createEntity({
    name: "player",
    shape: "circle",
    radius: 1,
    /*image: "pig.png",*/
    imageStretchToFit: true,
    density: 4,
    x: 2,
    onKeyDown: function(e) {
      this.applyImpulse(200, 60);
    }
  });
  
  world.createEntity({
    name: "ground",
    shape: "square",
    type: "static",
    color: "rgb(0,100,0)",
    width: 20,
    height: .5,
    y: 12
  });
  
  var block = {
    name: "block",
    shape: "square",
    color: "brown",
    width: .5,
    height: 4,
    onImpact: function(entity, force) {
      if (entity.name() === "player") {
        this.color("black");
      }
    }
  };
  
  world.createEntity(block, {
    x: 15
  });
  
  world.createEntity(block, {
    x: 17
  });
  
  world.createEntity(block, {
    x: 16,
    y: 1,
    width: 4,
    height: .5
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="http://incompl.github.io/boxbox/boxbox/Box2dWeb-2.1.a.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://incompl.github.io/boxbox/boxbox/boxbox.js"></script>

<canvas id="game" width=640 height=380>You don't support Canvas :(</canvas>
```

*jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/enp7ocrL/*
*codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLbQpz*

**Make sure you have these following issues covered, I think the problem lies here somewhere:**

- Link to the correct files for the *Box2dWeb* and *boxbox* (just to be sure).
  Those JS-files should look like this: [Box2dWeb](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/incompl/boxbox/master/Box2dWeb-2.1.a.3.min.js) and [boxbox](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/incompl/boxbox/master/boxbox.min.js).
- Make sure your folder structure is correct (all files in the same folder):
  ▼ www.website.com/path/to/folder/
        *Box2dWeb-2.1.a.3.min.js*
        *boxbox.min.js*
        *game.js*
        *index.html*
        *pig.png*
- Make sure *pig.png* is actually there! This crashed the whole thing for me, I had to remove that line in your *game.js* for it to work: `/*image: "pig.png",*/`.
- Not 100% sure about this one, but it wouldn't surprise me if this only works on an actual server (i.e. NOT on your local machine, opening the *index.html* file from your Windows/Mac/whatever explorer).
  Alternatively, you could use [**XAMPP**](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) to run on local machine (it simulates running on a remote server), but in my opinion the real thing is always best. *[Some tutorials on installing XAMPP.](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=how+to+install+xampp)*
- ***(This is not necessary if you put the `<script src="game.js"></script>` inside the `<body>` and after the `<canvas>`, like you have in your question.)***
  Wrap your *game.js* code inside a `document.ready` or `window.load` event-handler.
  I think `document.ready` is probably preferred, but in *pure JS* that's not as easy as `window.load` (I use the latter in all three demos).
  If you want `document.ready`, *jQuery* offers `$(document).ready(function(){ your code });`, but I'm not sure if that's worth loading the whole jQuery-library, if this is the only thing you use it for.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put game.js in the original document. Also, the script src files shouldn't be in `<head>`, they should be in `<body>.`

Comment: Ok, i will try that. thank you.